# what is the difference between a flag and a teleporter?

Tags: starbound

I made and placed a flag on one of my planets, and it allows me to teleport to it from my ship. On another planet I placed a teleport booth, and it seems to do the same thing. In what way(s) is(are) a teleport booth better than than flag? What are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've bookmarked a teleporter you can teleport to it as well as use it to teleport to other bookmarked locations or party members the same way as you would from your ship.

Once a flag is bookmarked you can teleport to it from any teleporter, but once you are there you can not teleport out.

**Edit:**
It's worth noting that there is a difference between casual and normal in that you can only beam to ship from near the surface on normal. So if you are building under ground you cannot easily get anywhere else on normal mode (making teleporters more valuable).

Comment: Awesome! That's just what I needed to know. With that information, the extra step of having to jump to my ship before teleporting away seems like a pretty good tradeoff considering how much cheaper it is to produce flags compared to teleporters.

Comment: Teleporters are good for more permanent installations. For other stuff I'd go with flags indeed. Updated my answer with some information relating to normal vs casual. Not sure if it is of value to you, but good to know.

Comment: I usually play in casual mode, but a more complete answer helps anyone else who wants more info.